# Excel - How to convert Day of Week - Mon - Day - UTC - Year to recognizable date in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on a file that pulls data directly from a web source, but I need to calculate time elapsed since a date. The problem is this is the format the date is appearing in:

```
Sun May 08 00:00:00 UTC 2016
```

How to I convert this automatically to MM/DD/YYYY when I refresh the data so that it appears as:

```
05/08/2016
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=--(MID(A1,9,2)&MID(A1,4,5)&RIGHT(A1,4))
```

and format the output however you want:

[image]